# Handling missing data - secondary driver characteristics in insurance data

Tags: machine-learning, data-cleaning, data-science-model, data-analysis, missing-data

I have an insurance dataset which includes an indicator that indicates whether the policy insures a secondary driver, and the secondary driver's age/sex. Problem is most policies do not have secondary drivers, so when preprocessing the data how should I handle the secondary driver's age/sex - deleting those observations is not an option because about 30% of policies have secondary drivers. Should I encode the secondary driver's age as zero?

Comment: What is the use case you are trying to solve with this dataset?

Comment: Trying to predict cost of claims for each policy